# HiltViewModel is reset, losing data when change of composable in Jetpack Compose app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I was developing an Jepack Compose app where I have some login, which give access to the main dashboard which have some screens.

My problem is I'm using StateFlow to keep data into my SharedViewModel, but this data is reset when I change of composable, possibly because my SharedViewModel is been reset, when I change from the login navigation graph to the dashboard  navigation graph, where the value store in the sessionID StateFlow is been reset.

My MainActivty class is this

MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setUpUi()
    }

    private fun setUpUi() {
        setContent {
            PayAtTheTableTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = Screens.Auth.route
                ) {
                    navigation(
                        startDestination = Screens.Login.route,
                        route = Screens.Auth.route
                    ) {
                        composable(Screens.Login.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
                            Surface(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                            ) {
                                LoginScreen(
                                    navController,
                                    context = applicationContext,
                                    viewModel = navBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(
                                        navController = navController
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        composable(Screens.Settings.route) {navBackStackEntry ->
                            Surface(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                color = PrimaryColor
                            ) {
                                SettingsScreen(
                                    context = applicationContext,
                                    navController = navController,
                                    sharedPreferences = AppModule().provideSharedPreferences(context = applicationContext),
                                    viewModel = navBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController = navController)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    navigation(
                        startDestination = Screens.Consult.route,
                        route = Screens.Dashboard.route
                    ) {
                        composable(Screens.Consult.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
                            Surface(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                            ) {
                                TableQueryScreen(
                                    navBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController = navController),
                                    context = applicationContext,
                                    navController = navController
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        composable(
                            route = Screens.Consulted.route,
                            arguments = listOf(
                                navArgument("list") {
                                    type =
                                        NavType.inferFromValueType(listOf<CheckInfoDomain>())
                                }
                            )
                        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
                            Surface(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                            ) {
                                TableResultScreen(
                                    itemsList = listOf(),
                                    viewModel = navBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController = navController),
                                    context = applicationContext,
                                    navController = navController
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        composable(
                            route = Screens.Detail.route,
                            arguments = listOf(
                                navArgument("detail"){
                                    type = NavType.StringType
                                }
                            )
                        ){navBackStackEntry ->
                                val detail = remember {
                                    navBackStackEntry.arguments?.getString("detail")
                                }
                                detail?.let {
                                    DetailPaymentScreen(
                                        context = applicationContext,
                                        navController = navController,
                                        args = it
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        composable(
                            route = Screens.PaymentProgress.route
                            ){navBackStackEntry ->
                                PaymentProgressScreen(
                                    context = applicationContext,
                                    viewModel = navBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController = navController)
                                )
                            }
                        composable(
                            route = Screens.PaymentResult.route
                            ){navBackStackEntry ->
                                PaymentResultScreen(
                                    context = applicationContext ,
                                    navController = navController,
                                    viewModel = navBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController = navController)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    /**
     * Function to instantiate viewmodel, passing route in case it exits.
     */
    @Composable
    fun NavBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(navController: NavController): SharedViewModel {
        val navGraphRoute = destination.parent?.route ?: return hiltViewModel()
        val parentEntry = remember(this) {
            navController.getBackStackEntry(navGraphRoute)
        }
        return hiltViewModel(parentEntry)
    }
}
```

Regarding my Login Screen:

LoginScreen.kt

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(navController: NavController, context: Context, viewModel: SharedViewModel) {
    var employeeId by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    var shopNumber by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    var terminalNumber by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val loginResponse by viewModel.loginResponseDTO.collectAsState()
    val showDialog: Boolean by viewModel.showDialog.collectAsState()
    val errorMessage: String by viewModel.messageDialog.collectAsState()
    val showLoading:Boolean by viewModel.showLoading.collectAsState()

    PayAtTheTableTheme {
        Surface {
            if (showDialog) {
                SimpleAlertDialog(
                    context = context,
                    show = true,
                    title = context.getString(R.string.titleError),
                    text = errorMessage,
                    onConfirm = viewModel::onDialogConfirm ,
                    onDismiss = viewModel::onDialogDismiss,
                    elevation = 10
                )
            }
            if(showLoading){
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize() // it will fill parent box
                    .padding(8.dp)
                ) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                }
            }
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding((width / 20).dp)) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted),
                    contentDescription = "Settings",
                    Modifier
                        .clickable { navController.navigate(Screens.Settings.route) }
                        .align(Alignment.End)
                        .size(Utils.convertPixelsToDp((width / 6).toFloat(), context).dp)
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo_paytef),
                    contentDescription = "logo",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .fillMaxHeight(0.2f)
                )
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = shopNumber,
                    label = { Text(text = context.getString(R.string.numberShow)) },
                    onValueChange = { shopNumber = it },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )

                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = employeeId,
                    label = { Text(text = context.getString(R.string.idEmployee)) },
                    onValueChange = { employeeId = it },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = terminalNumber,
                    label = { Text(text = context.getString(R.string.terminalNumber)) },
                    onValueChange = { terminalNumber = it },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))

                FloatingActionButton(
                    onClick = {
                        val loginRequest = LoginRequestDTO(
                            storeNo = shopNumber,
                            deviceNo = terminalNumber,
                            userID = employeeId
                        )
                        try {
                            viewModel.login(loginRequest, context).also {
                                if(loginResponse?.respCode == "00"){
                                    viewModel.setEmployeeId(employeeId)
                                    viewModel.setShopNumber(shopNumber)
                                    viewModel.setTerminalNumber(terminalNumber)
                                    navController.navigate(Screens.Dashboard.route)
                                }else{
                                    viewModel.showDialog(context.getString(R.string.textError))
                                }
                            }
                        }catch (e:Exception){
                            e.message?.let {msg ->
                                viewModel.showDialog(msg)
                            }
                        }

                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(text = context.getString(R.string.enter))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I check that sessionId is correctly setted into my SharedViewModel at firts when  still stay on Login Screen, but when I change the NavGraph to Dashboard, sessionId value is reset to an empt string.

Here my SharedViewModel

SharedViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle, @ApplicationContext context:Context) : ViewModel() {

    @Inject lateinit var loginUseCase : LoginUseCase

    @Inject lateinit var transactionUseCase: TransactionUseCase

    @Inject lateinit var getCheckOutInfoUseCase: GetCheckOutInfoUseCase

    @Inject lateinit var getDisconnectUseCase: GetDisconnectUseCase

    @Inject lateinit var getPostPaymentUseCase: GetPostPaymentUseCase

    private val _showDialog = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val showDialog: StateFlow<Boolean> = _showDialog.asStateFlow()

    private val _showLoading:MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val showLoading:StateFlow<Boolean> = _showLoading.asStateFlow()

    private val _messageDialog = MutableStateFlow(context.getString(R.string.textError))
    val messageDialog: StateFlow<String> = _messageDialog.asStateFlow()

    private val _loginResponseDTO: MutableStateFlow<LoginResponseDTO?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val loginResponseDTO: StateFlow<LoginResponseDTO?> = _loginResponseDTO.asStateFlow()

    private val _getCheckOutInfoResp : MutableStateFlow<GetCheckInfoResponseDTO?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val getCheckOutInfoResp: StateFlow<GetCheckInfoResponseDTO?> = _getCheckOutInfoResp.asStateFlow()

    private val _getPaymentResultResp : MutableStateFlow<String?> = MutableStateFlow(context.getString(
        R.string.processing
    ))
    val getPaymentResultResp : StateFlow<String?> = _getPaymentResultResp.asStateFlow()

    private val _getPostPaymentResultResp: MutableStateFlow<TransactionResult?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val getPostPaymentResp :StateFlow<TransactionResult?> = _getPostPaymentResultResp.asStateFlow()

    private val _disconnectResp : MutableStateFlow<DisconnectResponseDTO?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val disconnectResp :StateFlow<DisconnectResponseDTO?> = _disconnectResp.asStateFlow()

    fun onDialogConfirm() {
        _showDialog.value = false
    }

    fun onDialogDismiss() {
        _showDialog.value = false
    }

    fun showDialog(msg:String){
        _messageDialog.value = msg
        _showDialog.value = true
    }

    fun login(loginRequest: LoginRequestDTO, context:Context) {
        _showLoading.value = true
        if(updateUseCase.value){
            loginUseCase = LoginUseCase(AppModule().providePayAtTAbleApi(AppModule().provideSharedPreferences(context))) // Reinizialite loginUseCase, to update ip in case it'd have been changed
        }
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                loginUseCase.login(request = loginRequest).also {
                    loginUseCase.loginResponseDTO?.let {
                        _loginResponseDTO.value = it
                        _sessionId.value = it.sessionID
                        _showLoading.value = false
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _messageDialog.value = e.message ?: context.getString(R.string.textError)
            _showLoading.value = false
            _showDialog.value = true
        }
    }
    fun getCheckOutInfo(request: GetCheckInfoRequestDTO, context: Context) {
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                _showLoading.value = true
                getCheckOutInfoUseCase.getCheckOutInfo(request)
                getCheckOutInfoUseCase.checkOutInfoResponse.let {
                    _getCheckOutInfoResp.value = it
                    _showLoading.value = false
                }
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            _messageDialog.value = e.message ?: context.getString(R.string.textError)
            _showLoading.value = false
            _showDialog.value = true
        }
    }

    fun getPaymentTransaction(transaction: CheckInfoDomain, context: Context){
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                _showLoading.value = true
               val transacionResult = transactionUseCase.transactionProcess(transaction, _getPaymentResultResp)

                if(transacionResult.acepted){
                        val req = PostPaymentRequestDTO(
                        tableNo = transaction.checkEmp,
                        checkNum = transaction.checkNum,
                        transType = "01",
                        transAmount = transaction.paymentDue.toString(),
                        otherAmount = "",
                        transCurrency = "978",
                        rnn = "",
                        alternateTransRef = "",
                        transToken = "",
                        issuerId = "",
                        pan = "",
                        expiryDate = "",
                        authCode = "",
                        entryMode = "",
                        transDateTime = "",
                        merchantId = "",
                        terminalId = "",
                        sessionID = sessionId.value,
                        cCSurchargeAmount = "",
                        donationsAmount = ""
                    )
                    getPostPayment(context = context, request = req)
                    _getPostPaymentResultResp.value = transacionResult
                }else{
                    refundTransaction(transaction, context)
                    _getPostPaymentResultResp.value = transacionResult
                    _messageDialog.value = transacionResult.text
                    _showDialog.value = true
                }
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            refundTransaction(transaction, context)
            _messageDialog.value = e.message ?: context.getString(R.string.textError)
            _showDialog.value = true
        }
    }

    private fun refundTransaction(transaction: CheckInfoDomain, context: Context) {
        val req = PostPaymentRequestDTO(
            tableNo = transaction.checkEmp,
            checkNum = transaction.checkNum,
            transType = "03",
            transAmount = transaction.paymentDue.toString(),
            otherAmount = "",
            transCurrency = "978",
            rnn = "",
            alternateTransRef = "",
            transToken = "",
            issuerId = "",
            pan = "",
            expiryDate = "",
            authCode = "",
            entryMode = "",
            transDateTime = "",
            merchantId = "",
            terminalId = terminalNumber.value,
            sessionID = sessionId.value,
            cCSurchargeAmount = "",
            donationsAmount = ""
        )
        getPostPayment(context = context, request = req)
    }

    private fun getPostPayment(request: PostPaymentRequestDTO, context: Context){
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                getPostPaymentUseCase.getPostPayment(request = request)
                getPostPaymentUseCase.getPostPaymentResponseDTO.let{postPaymentResp ->
                    if(postPaymentResp?.respCode.equals("00")){
                        val req = DisconnectRequestDTO(
                            sessionID = sessionId.value,
                            deviceNo = terminalNumber.value,
                            userID = employeeId.value,
                            storeNo = shopNumber.value
                        )
                        disconnect(context = context, request = req)
                    }else if(postPaymentResp?.respCode.equals("45")){
                        _messageDialog.value = postPaymentResp?.respText ?: context.getString(R.string.sendError)
                        _showDialog.value = true
                        _showLoading.value = false
                    }else if(postPaymentResp?.respCode.equals("96")){
                        _messageDialog.value = context.getString(R.string.textError)
                        _showDialog.value = true
                        _showLoading.value = false
                    }else{
                        _messageDialog.value = context.getString(R.string.textError)
                        _showDialog.value = true
                        _showLoading.value = false
                    }
                    /**TODO: RespCode
                     * 00: Approval -> Call disconect
                     * 45: Posting Failure -> show error message & refund payment
                     * 96: System error -> show error message & refund payment
                     */
                }
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            _messageDialog.value = e.message ?: context.getString(R.string.textError)
            _showLoading.value = false
            _showDialog.value = true
        }
    }

    private fun disconnect(request: DisconnectRequestDTO, context: Context){
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                getDisconnectUseCase.disconect(request)
                getDisconnectUseCase.disconnectResponse.let{
                    _disconnectResp.value = it
                    _showLoading.value = false
                }
            }
        }catch (e:Exception){
            _messageDialog.value = e.message ?: context.getString(R.string.textError)
            _showLoading.value = false
            _showDialog.value = true
        }
    }

    //Keep data of login in State

    private val _sessionId :MutableStateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow("")
    val sessionId:StateFlow<String> = _sessionId.asStateFlow()

    /** Change to regular StateFlow due to doens't keep the value.
    var sessionIdState : StateFlow<String> =
        savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("sessionId", loginResponseDTO.value?.sessionID ?: "")

    fun setSessionId(sessionId:String){
        savedStateHandle["sessionId"] = sessionId
    }

    */
    val employeeId :StateFlow<String> =
        savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("employeeId", "")

    fun setEmployeeId(employeeId:String){
        savedStateHandle["employeeId"] = employeeId
    }

    val shopNumber: StateFlow<String?> =
        savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("shopNumber", "")

    fun setShopNumber(shopNumber:String){
        savedStateHandle["shopNumber"] = shopNumber
    }

    val terminalNumber :StateFlow<String> =
        savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("terminalNumber", "")

    fun setTerminalNumber(terminalNumber:String){
        savedStateHandle["terminalNumber"] = terminalNumber
    }

    //Variable to update ip of payAtTable api, in case it'd have been updated in Settings screen
    val updateUseCase: StateFlow<Boolean> =
        savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("updateUseCase", false)

    fun setUpdateUseCase(updateUseCase: Boolean){
        savedStateHandle["updateUseCase"] = updateUseCase
    }
}
```

As you can check i'm using Hilt to inject my viewModel.

The crash comes when I try to makke the next call in my firts dashboard screen: TableQueryScreen, which used a custom component: QueryTableCard

TableQueryScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun TableQueryScreen(sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel, context: Context, navController: NavController) {
    Surface {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)
        ) {
            QueryTableCard(
                title = context.getString(R.string.table),
                placeHolderPutLineText = context.getString(R.string.tableNumber),
                viewModel = sharedViewModel,
                context = context,
                navController = navController
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(15.dp))
            QueryTableCard(
                title = context.getString(R.string.account),
                placeHolderPutLineText = context.getString(R.string.accountNumber),
                viewModel = sharedViewModel,
                context = context,
                navController = navController
            )
        }
    }
}
```

QueryTableCard.kt

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun QueryTableCard(
    title: String,
    placeHolderPutLineText: String,
    viewModel: SharedViewModel,
    context: Context,
    navController :NavController
) {

    val height = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val list by viewModel.getCheckOutInfoResp.collectAsState()
    val showLoading: Boolean by viewModel.showLoading.collectAsState()
    var inputText by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }


    PayAtTheTableTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = PrimaryColor))
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            shadowElevation = 20.dp,
            tonalElevation = 20.dp,
        ) {
            if (showLoading) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(1.0f) // it will fill parent box
                        .padding(8.dp)
                ) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                }
            }
            Card(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 20.dp)
            ) {
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(15.dp)
                        .wrapContentHeight()
                ) {
                    Text(text = title, Modifier.padding(horizontal = 5.dp))
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = inputText,
                        label = { Text(text = placeHolderPutLineText)},
                        onValueChange = { inputText = it },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(5.dp))
                    Button(
                        onClick = {
                            try {
                                val request = GetCheckInfoRequestDTO(
                                    tableNo = inputText,
                                    sessionID = viewModel.sessionId.value
                                )
                                viewModel.getCheckOutInfo(request = request, context = context)
                                if (list?.checkInfo?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
                                    list?.let {
                                        val transformList =
                                            DomainMapper.listCheckInfoDataToCheckInfoDomain(
                                                it.checkInfo,
                                                viewModel.sessionId.value  // This value is empty on this screen
                                            )
                                        navController.navigate(route = "result/$transformList")
                                    }

                                }
                            }catch (e:Exception){
                                e.message?.let { viewModel.showDialog(it) }
                            }
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height((height / 25).dp)
                            .background(PrimaryColor)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = context.getString(R.string.consult), modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I need a sessionId value to make the next call, but as I said on this NavGraph is empty, due to the behaviour of HiltViewModel.

I don't know if I should use SharedFow instead StateFlow to keep this kind of data.

Take thanks in advance !

Comment: Why don't you inject ViewModel into the activity and then just pass it as an argument to specific composables?

Comment: It's what i'm doing on function NavBackStackEntry.sharedViewModel(), where I recover the navigation route in case it's exist.

Comment: Yes, I see. You don't need that method, inject ViewModel into MainActivity like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodels) and pass it to composables where required. That's it